# Singularities of a complex function in the punctured disc

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic funclion in the punctured disc $\{z: 0<|z|<1\}$ such that $|f(z)|\leq 100 + |\log|z||$, $\forall z\in\mathbb{C}$. Does the point admit a singularity?

Comment: You don't mean all $z \in \mathbb C$, since it's only defined for $0 < |z| < 1$.

Comment: And what do you mean by "admit a singularity"?  By definition there is a singularity at $z=0$, since $f$ is not defined there; the question is whether it is removable.

Comment: Do you know Riemann's theorem about removable singularities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Riemann's theorem on removable singularities
$$ \bigl\lvert \oint_{\gamma_C} f(z) z^n\,dz \bigr\rvert \leq \oint_{\gamma_C} \bigl\lvert f(z) z^n\bigr\rvert\,dz \leq \oint_{\gamma_C} (100 + \mid \log \mid z \mid \mid) \bigl\lvert z^n\bigr\rvert\,dz = \\ = 2\pi r^{n+1}100 + \int_{0}^{2\pi}r^n \mid \log r \mid d\varphi \\ \leq 2\pi r^{n+1}+2\pi r^{n-\frac{1}{2}} \rightarrow 0, r\rightarrow 0$$ where $\gamma_C$ is the path of a small circle around $0$.

This shows that at $0$, the function $f$ has a removable singularity.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: estimate $\left|\oint_C f(z) z^n \; dz\right|$ where $C$ is a small circle around $0$.